# Python beginner- Repeat LINE or FOR loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

This is my project. Please understand that I'm a beginner.

Problem: I have to repeat from this line `for k, v in d.items() :` every time **user_input** is **Y** and **break** every time is **N**. I don't know if I can repeat from the line number or from the `for` or from the `while` on the previous line.

Maybe I can `def` before the `for` or there's any way of repeating from wherever you want.

Thank you for reading.

Code:

```
elif action.lower() == 'add':
        table = input ('Select desired table number: \n - ...')
        fulltab = 'T' + table
        with open(fulltab + '.txt', 'w+') as f :
            for k, v in d.items() :
                print(k, v)
            #print('Select codes: \n -...')
            addprod = input('Insert order. \n - ...')
            for k, v in d.items() :
                if addprod == k[1] :
                    print('Added:', k, v)
            q = input('Add more? y/n')
            if q.lower() == 'y' : continue
            if q.lower() == 'n' : break
```

Full code for better understanding:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as r :
    f_n = r.read().splitlines()
print("Welcome to NAME.app")
##############
# USER LOGIN #
##############
while True:
    name = input("""
    \n - Insert name to logg in
    \n - ADD to save new user
    \n - LIST to see saved users
    \n - REMOVE to delete a user
    \n - EXIT to finish
    \n - ...""")

    lname = name.lower()

    if lname == "add":
        n_input = input("Name:")
        with open('names.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(n_input + '\n')

    elif lname == "list":
        with open('names.txt') as f:
            print(f.read().splitlines())
            f.close()

    elif name in f_n:
        print("Logged as", name.upper())
        input('Welcome, press enter to continue \n')
        break

    elif lname == 'remove':
        rem = input("Insert user name to remove \n ...")
        with open('names.txt', 'r+') as f:
            l = f.readlines()
            l = [z for z in l if rem not in z]
        with open('names.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.writelines(l)

    elif lname == "exit":
        exit()
####################
# TABLE MANAGEMENT #
####################

while True:
    action = input ('''
 - NEW table
    \n - ADD table
    \n - BILL
    \n - ... ''')

    d = {'(1) chburger': 19,'(2) bncburger': 23,'(3) plpasta': 6}

    if action == 'new' :
        tn = input('Insert table number \n - ...')
        name = 'T' + tn
        t = open(name + '.txt', 'w+')
        print('Done')


    elif action.lower() == 'add':
        table = input ('Select desired table number: \n - ...')
        fulltab = 'T' + table
        with open(fulltab + '.txt', 'w+') as f :
            for k, v in d.items() :
                print(k, v)
            #print('Select codes: \n -...')
            addprod = input('Insert order. \n - ...')
            for k, v in d.items() :
                if addprod == k[1] :
                    print('Added:', k, v)
            q = input('Add more? y/n')
            if q.lower() == 'y' : continue
            if q.lower() == 'n' : break

 #File as F

    elif action.lower() == 'bill' :
        p_b = input('Please insert number of table. \n -... ')
        with open (('T' + p_b)+ '.txt', 'r+') as p :
            tobill = 0
            for line in p : tobill = int(tobill) + int(line)

    

    #print('Total to pay:', tobill)

        xtra = input('Group table (+10 ppl)? y/n: \n')
        if xtra == 'y' :
            tobill = tobill + (tobill/100)*10
            print('SERVICE CHARGE ADDED.')

        elif xtra == 'n' : print ('Processing bill...')
        print('Total to pay:', tobill)

elif action.lower() == "exit":
    exit()
```

Comment: If you have a "Someone" and "o`Som Gone" in your names.txt and remove the name "Som" ... what happens?

Comment: In your `àdd` codepart you open a file but never write anything to it - why?

Comment: what happens if no names.txt is present if you start it?

Comment: You can simply add another `while True:` after `with open(fulltab + '.txt', 'w+') as f :`  and indent the code that handles inputting one item once. If the user then gives a ``q` of `'n'` you break from that while. Not sure what your real problem is ...

Comment: @PatrickArtner 1) I can just hope that no waiter/tress logs in as that haha(will be one of the last things to fix). 2) I suppose that with the first line `with open`` the file will be created automatically. 3) That's perfect, I suppose it will work. My problem was how to repeat all that code and with this answer, just thinking about it I know will work. Thank you for taking the time Patrick. The add code part doesn't write anything because is the last thing to do on that line. But it will write to ``file.txt`` the ``values`` selected from the ``dictionary``. Sorry for not adding it.

Answer (score 0):

`break` statement break **only** nearest `for / whille`.

an example:

```
n = 6
while n > 4:
    print(">>>>>> n:", n)
    n-=1
    for i in range(3):
        print(">>> i:", i)
        for x in range(2):
            print("x:", x)
            if x == 1:
                print("BREAK_____ inner for")
                break
```

```
>>>>>> n: 6
>>> i: 0
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
>>> i: 1
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
>>> i: 2
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
>>>>>> n: 5
>>> i: 0
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
>>> i: 1
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
>>> i: 2
x: 0
x: 1
BREAK_____ inner for
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
elif action.lower() == 'add':
        table = input ('Select desired table number: \n - ...')
        fulltab = 'T' + table
        with open(fulltab + '.txt', 'w+') as f :
            for k, v in d.items() :
                print(k, v)
            #print('Select codes: \n -...')
            addprod = input('Insert order. \n - ...')
            for k, v in d.items() :
                if addprod == k[1] :
                    print('Added:', k, v)
            q = input('Add more? y/n')
            if q == 'n':
                exit()
            else:
                while q.lower() == 'y' :
                    for k, v in d.items() :
                    if addprod == k[1] :
                        print('Added:', k, v)
                    q = input('Add more? y/n')
```

Comment: Hey, it would be worth explaining what you changed/fixed from the code in the question.